# Unknown build error

Tags: c#, wpf, compiler-errors

I followed [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23731/RecentFileList-a-WPF-MRU) link to make use of "recent files list" but statement below causes build error. BTW, I referenced dll file. `xmlns:common="clr-namespace:Common"` works good but when I add the rest it does not work.

```
xmlns:common="clr-namespace:Common; assembly=RecentFileListLib"
```

Error message:

`Error  1   Unknown build error, ''clr-namespace:Common; assembly=RecentFileListLib' mapping URI is not valid. Line 4 Position 9.'`

Comment: Can you show the build error message?

Comment: If you mention that you get an error - be nice and add error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from article comment:

> I have just downloaded the software and I thought it worth mentioning
>   that it is likely folk will do a copy and paste of 
>   xmlns:common="clr-namespace:Common; assembly=RecentFileListLib"
>   directly from your article. However I notice that the space between
>   Common; and assembly is thrown as an error in the XAML file. **removing
>   the space and all works fine**.

Comment: Where is that article? I still have problems with the rest of the file :)

Comment: You added [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23731/RecentFileList-a-WPF-MRU) to that article :)

Comment: Yeah :) Someone also mentioned `FileOpenCore()` but still I dont understand. Believe me this is my last question: what should I replace for that `FileOpenCore()`?

Comment: As I understood, that method should open file. That means that your app opens selected file.